# How can I use dual_coef_ param after SVM learning in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, scikit-learn

As I know, SVM decision function with rbf kernel looks like [here on slide 22](https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/ml/docs%2Fslides%2FLecture12.pdf).

After SVM learning

```
from sklearn import svm
X = [[0, 0], [1, 1]]
y = [0, 1]
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X, y)
```

how can I see coefficients `theta_i` for decision function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if classes [0, 1] given as labels for libsvm, then sv_coef will be generated to determine 0 class. But if we'll give [1, 0], then sv_coef will be generated for 1 class.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [official documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) (See the **Attributes** section). You are probably looking for `dual_coef_`.

```
>>> from sklearn import svm

>>> X = [[0, 0], [1, 1]]
>>> y = [0, 1]
>>> clf = svm.SVC()
>>> clf.fit(X, y)
>>> clf.dual_coef_
array([[ 1., -1.]])
>>> clf.support_vectors_
array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.]])
```

Comment: Yes, I've found it, but

1 * f1 - 1 * f2 will give us positive value for [0, 0] and negative for [1, 1]. May be desicion function in libsvm looks like something else than here: https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/ml/docs%2Fslides%2FLecture12.pdf

Comment: @user3142484, it depends on the point you evaluate `f1` and `f2`. You should evaluate both at the same point and find the sign of the total sum you just made. This will tell to which class(0 or 1) the point belongs.

Comment: f1 = exp( -gamma * ||x-[0, 0]||^2 )
f2 = exp( -gamma * ||x-[1, 1]||^2 )

so for [0, 0] f1 will be bigger than f2 and f1-f2 > 0 and then predictions should be 1

Comment: @user3142484, just to be clear: do you know the methods `predict` and `decision_function`? Is your intention to find out how libsvm works?